# cmd after createdb command with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cmd, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 and i'm trying to learn about creating databases using postgresql but i can't even create a simple testing table. I'm checking guides for about 3 hours now on how to start but with my little knowledge about ubuntu i don't understand much and thats why i try asking here. I will write the steps i follow because i'm not sure where the mistake is. I installed postgresql using the commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

After that i use

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

to log in to the autocreated user account postgres and then

```
psql
```

to be able to interact with the db management system.
After that i write

```
createdb testingdb
```

in order to make the first step and then \l to check if it is created but the outcome of \l is a list of 3 databases (3 rows postgres template0 template 1) without the testingdb being there. Also at this point the cmd is frozen and looks likes this

```
the list of the 3 databases
(3 rows)
~
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

Any hint will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing two separate ways of creating a database:

**Method 1**

```
psql               #(Type this on the shell prompt)
CREATE DATABASE testingdb;

\c testingdb
CREATE TABLE tbl1(a INT);
\q
```

**Method 2**

```
createdb testingdb #(Again, type this on the shell prompt, not inside psql!)

psql testingdb
CREATE TABLE tbl1(a INT);
\q
```

The last bit about stuck prompt, is because you probably are inside the psql prompt, and to come back to the shell prompt, you need to type \q (or Control-d).

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help. Both ways work for creating a database but CREATE TABLE tbl1; triggers ERROR:  syntax error at or near  ";" . This happens in both ways.

Comment: The error was because i had to write CREATE TABLE tbl1(); at least. I'm sorry asking wrong stuff cause of my lack of knowledge...thnx again

Comment: Yeah, that was more of an example, rather than a working SQL. Its updated and working now.